# area51: proposal fulfilled after 9 questions/answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

> I commit to participate actively in (PROPOSAL) for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

It seems like they don't care about anything but the 10 posts. On math I currently have [9 posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/104/crazyjugglerdrummer) and have been told I fulfilled my commitment shortly after posting my 7th, 8th, and 9th that day. (sorry if I post more stuff soon :)

(I know its really minor, but somebody had to report it).

Comment: Perhaps one more post that's deleted?

Answer (score 3):

The rules are only guidelines. We don't publish the exact algorithm that judges fulfillment of commitment to a proposal.

Bottom line: please actively participate -- ask and answer questions -- during beta on proposals you've committed to. The rest will take care of itself.

Comment: Ask AND answer? My pattern is to ask (SU, SF), OR answer (SO, Programmers, Cooking, English). It's not a deliberate choice, just how I appear to end up. Should I go out of my way to do both during a beta just to technically fulfill my committment, or will plenty of answering suffice?