# When is commitment to SharePoint Overflow fullfiled?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

Currently I can't commit to a proposal, because I committed to SharePoint Overflow which skipped the private beta.  Contrary to

> You'll be able to commit to another
>   proposal once one of the above sites'
>   beta launches, and you follow through
>   on your commitment to that site. See
>   the FAQ section on commitment for more
>   details.

SharePoint Overflow is listed as one of my current proposals

Answer (score 5):

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta (up to 90 days).

From

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Jeff [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62324/area51-proposal-fulfilled-after-9-questions-answers/62339#62339)

> The rules are only guidelines. We don't publish the exact algorithm that judges fulfillment of commitment to a proposal.

Currently you don't have any questions/answers there. You might need some participations there to get your commitment fulfilled.